# Out of Memory Error when Loading Images from Mipmap folder

Tags: android, out-of-memory, mipmaps

Logcat
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                    Process: com.example.markpalmer.blackjack21, PID: 21864                                                                                    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 5808012 byte allocation with 5226696 free bytes and 4MB until OOM

Hi, I know there are some posts regarding this, but I don't really understand the answers. The error is random, and occurs when setting an imageview:

ivPlayerCard3.setImageResource(picP3);

The images are not large: 36kb, 500x700 .png files.  The thing is for no particular reason I have put them in the res>mipmap-hdpi folder. Could this be the reason for my problem. Would shifting them to the drawable folder help?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try setting thee imageResouce using well known libraries like `Picasso` check the doc [here](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

`Picasso` handles OOM very well by loading the image in segments or fractions. Also moving them to drawable might help as mipmap actually creates a map of the image, but a better solution is to use Picasso hope this helps!

Comment: Hi. Where does the Picasso download go in relation to Android Studio please. Sorry, not the best of questions, but I don't know what to do with it

Comment: Sorry, I've found a pretty in depth post - I will give it a blast

Comment: Hey, no worries, you can add it to your app via the `build.gradle` (app) file. 
Look for the `dependency{...}` object and add this there `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'` sync your project and you're good to go!